Write $\frac{\sqrt{x+a}}{x+b}$ as a series of fractions of the form $\frac{1}{x+c}$ or $\frac{1}{x(x+d)}$?
I need to approximate the function $\frac{\sqrt{x+a}}{x+b}$ as a series of fractions of the type $\frac{1}{x+c}$ or $\frac{1}{x(x+d)}$, i.e.
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+a}}{x+b}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e_n\frac{1}{x+c_n}+f_n\frac{1}{x(x+d_n)}\right),$$
where $a$ and $b$ are given constants and $c_n, d_n, e_n, f_n$ to be determined. With rising $n$ the sum should get closer to the actual function; I need this for a numerical approximation of the given function.
I am completely clueless where to start and would be very thankfull for any advice!
